# Howto get list of IIS changes

Tags: iis

I've made some tweaks here and there on an IIS7, and am about to migrate to IIS8. How can I get a good overview of the things I've been poking with? Mime-types, rewrite-rules etc.

WinMerge would be nice - towards the default files. But I'm guessing IIS won't let me of the hook that easy, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides application level configs, you can try to WinMerge on the following configuration files:

- `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\framework_version\CONFIG\machine.config`
- `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\framework_version\CONFIG\Web.config`
- `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\ApplicationHost.config`